# Code Curiosity in C#

Tags: c#, label, goto

I was looking at the [YUI Compressor](http://yuicompressor.codeplex.com/SourceControl/ListDownloadableCommits.aspx) and came across this piece of code in the ECMA.NET project (Continuation file if you are interested).

```
protected internal override int FindPrototypeId (string s)
    {
        int id;
        #region Generated PrototypeId Switch
    L0: {
            id = 0;
            string X = null;
            if (s.Length == 11) { X = "constructor"; id = Id_constructor; }
            if (X != null && X != s && !X.Equals (s))
                id = 0;
        }
    EL0:
        #endregion
        return id;
    }
```

I have no idea what L0: and EL0: are doing here and have never seen this before. The term seems too rudimentary for google as well.

Anyone know anything about this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They look like lables for use as goto targets. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2.aspx for more information.

Comment: @Ty, @C. Ross: Yes, C# has goto's. In fact, loops are really nothing more than syntax sugar around a goto.

Answer (score 5):

They look like labels to me. The label is not used in this example (because it is generated code?), but can be used to jump another place. You could use `goto L0;` to jump the the first label. As an example, the following code writes just "Hello, World" because it skips the middle `Write()`:

```
Console.Write("Hello, ");
goto Last;
Console.Write("Cruel ");
Last:
Console.WriteLine("World");
```

Answer (score 2):

Those are labels, as in GOTO.

Answer (score 1):

They're obviously labels, but I don't think that they're used as goto targets.  I imagine that they're designed to be recognized by a code generation tool of some kind.  The code generation tool "owns" the code between L0 and EL0, which probably just means "end L0."

Answer (score 0):

L0 and EL0 look like labels for the [goto statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/13940fs2(VS.71).aspx)